# how can I make my ftp connect faster?

Tags: linux, ftp

I have a server with Debian 6, I installed the ftp service (ProFtp) but everytime I try to connect to my server first tries and get refused like 5 times (using different clients, but most of all filezilla) , I have no idea why is this, any missing configuration or delay or something.

Any idea of why is this? how can I make my conection faster and dont try many times until get connected?

the server has enough memory.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you see in the logs for the failed connection attempts?

Comment: yea, the problem is that it only says "conection refused by the server"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is reverse DNS.  See [here](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/directives/linked/config_ref_UseReverseDNS.html) and [here](http://www.computing.net/answers/linux/slow-ftp-reverse-dns-lookup/6284.html).

Edit `/etc/proftpd.conf` and change the directives:

```
UseReverseDNS on
IdentLookups on
```

to

```
UseReverseDNS off
IdentLookups off
```